# Double not changing its value properly

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate the Net Income based on a given Gross Income Value. The rules are this :

1. If grossValue is lower or equal to 1000, no tax is applied
2. 10% Tax is applied to the exess amout

Example : Given a gross value of 3400, we apply 10% tax to the exess so 10% out of 2400 is 240 => Then we just return 2160 + 1000

The problem is this line : `double netSalary = exessAmout - (10 / 100 * exessAmout);` For some reason the value doesnt change

```
public double CalculateNetSalary(double grossSalary)
{
    // Taxes dont apply, return grossValue
    if(grossSalary <= 1000)
    {
    return grossSalary;
    }

    double exessAmout = grossSalary - 1000;
    
    // Apply normal tax 
    double netSalary = exessAmout - (10 / 100 * exessAmout);
    
    return netSalary + 1000;
}
```

I expected given a value of 3400 to receive 3160

Why :

- exessAmout = 3400 - 1000 => 2400
- netSalary = 2400 - (10% of 2400)
- return netSalary + 1000

using a calculator to solve this I get the right answer, but running the code the value always stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing integer division. When you divide an `int` by another `int` then the result will be an `int`, which means that `10 / 100` will be zero. Make them `double` literals, i.e. `10.0 / 100.0`, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

First As mentioned jmcilhinney in his answer you need to make this `10 / 100` for double literals. and you expecting here 3160 as an answer? that expected result is breaking in here.

```
// Apply Social Tax
if (grossSalary > 3000)
{
    netSalary -= (10.0 / 100.0 * netSalary);
    Console.WriteLine(netSalary);
}
```

You have applied Social Tax for the `netSalary` value. 3160. According to it, output should be **2944**

Comment: Oh I forgot to delete the social tax, sorry. I deleted it so the question could be more simple.